# Regex between quotes look ahead - Python

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have this:

```
myText = str(^123"I like to"^456&U"play video games and"$"eat cereal")
```

I want to extract everything in between (and including) quotation marks, split everything before and after the `$` sign, and append them into a nested list.  E.g.

myTextList = [["I like to","play video games and"],["eat cereal"]]

This is what I tried:

```
tempTextList = []
for text in re.findall('(?<=\$)"[^"]*"(?<!\^)',myText,re.DOTALL)
    tempTextList.append(text)
myTextList.append(tempTextList)
```

I used the website https://www.regex101.com/#python and tried almost everything I could think of...

`(?!\$)"(?!\^\00\+\-\&)[^"].*"`
etc...

The re.findall part doesn't really work the way I want it to.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: do you want your results in a list like with quotes? or without?

Comment: You could show both.  I think `'"[^"]*"'` displays results with quotes and `"(.*?)"` displays results without quotes.

Comment: Do you want to split on `$` first and then find the quoted ?

Comment: There could be a number of sentences in between quotes with (and sometimes without) a `$` sign outside of the quotes.

Comment: If my answer worked for you please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `"[^"]*"` regex with `re.findall`:

```
import re
s = 'myText = str(^123"I like to"^456&U"play video games and"$"eat cereal")'
print(re.findall(r'"[^"]*"', s))
```

See [demo](http://ideone.com/2EmIcf)

It matches the double quoted substrings you need with double quotes: `['"I like to"', '"play video games and"', '"eat cereal"']`.

Note that `"[^"]*"` matches `"` followed by zero or more characters other than `"` followed with `"`.

If you need to get the contents inside `"..."` without the double quotes, you can use *capturing* mechanism:

```
r'"([^"]*)"'
```

The [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) will only return the captures in Group 1. See [another demo](http://ideone.com/aidLq5).

Comment: Wow that was fast!  Thanks @WiktorStribizew.  Also, just in case I don't want the double quoted substrings, I would use something like `"(.*?)"` instead of `'"[^"]*"'`, correct?

Comment: You can capture what is inside the double quotation marks. You can use `r'"([^"]*)"'` and access `group(1)`. Note that `.*?` is only good when you use DOTALL modifier and there is more than `"` at the end of the pattern. Note that `re.findall` will only return a list of captured substrings then.

Comment: If you need to match escaped entities inside, you may also use `r'"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"'` (or `r'"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"'` to get captures without double quotes).

Comment: This is likely one of the most useful Regex patterns out there. It can be a silver bullet for fast, powerful tokenizing.